# Xcode 8 Provisioning Profile only contains "Automatic"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

My new "Provisioning Profile" only shows "Automatic", my old "Deprecated" option correctly lists all my profiles. I've tried closing and re-opening, regenerating and re-downloading everything.

**Is there no way to target a specific profile anymore?**

[image: The new option shows only automatic]

Comment: Did you select "Automatic manage signing" in the "General" tab?

Comment: Thanks. It's not in in the search bar and I couldn't find the option. If you make it an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deactivate "Automatically manage signing" in the project's "General" tab. See screenshot for details.

[image]